# Inclusive meaning

Tags: writing, academic-writing

These example sentences are from Cambridge dictionary. One thing I can't understand is the use of the word *inclusive*. If I omit it, does it mean the same? The other example is the same. I don't know what meaning *inclusive* has added to both sentences.

> Children from age 13 to 17 inclusive are allowed to participate.
>
> The consultation period runs from December 2011 to April 2012 inclusive.

Answer (score 7):

It means that it includes the ends as well, **just to avoid any ambiguity** ("inclusive" *doesn’t change the meaning here*).

13 to 17 inclusive specifies that both ages 13 and 17 are included in the range, to preclude questions like "are 17 year olds allowed to participate or is the 17th birthday the limit?"

December 2011 to April 2012 inclusive means that the period starts first December 2011 and ends 30th April 2012.

Comment: Thank you. Please clarify if you please. 13 to 17 inclusive does it mean from the first day of age 13 to last day before 18 ? Right . How is it different from 13 to 17 are allowed to participate. Does this also means from the first day of 13 to the last day before turing 18 ?

Comment: Yes, @Rafeq, that’s what it means: one’s eligibility begins the moment one reaches age 13 and doesn’t end until the moment one turns 18. As the answer explains, *inclusive* doesn’t change the meaning here, but merely makes that meaning less ambiguous.

Comment: Added bold text and usage note ***just to avoid any ambiguity or uncertainty**!*

Comment: The opposite of this usage is "exclusive". "13 to 17 exclusive" means all ages between 13 and 17, excluding those two ages. Thus "13 to 17 exclusive" means the same thing as "14 to 16 inclusive".

Comment: @FumbleFingers thank you. One last question, sir what ambiguity may rise if I say football players from 17 to 23 can participate. It means all ages starting from 17,18,19,20,21,22, and less than 24 . Why should I write inclusive ? I somehow feels it is just a redundant in this context.

Comment: @YonKuma thank you. Does (exclusive) and (except for ) mean the same as : 1. many countries participate in the summit , except for the UK and France .  2. many countries participate in the summit exclusive of the UK and France .

Comment: @Rafeq These usages of "inclusive" and "exclusive" come from mathematics, so they don't map directly to other uses of the terms. Exclusive in this sense means "excluding," with the understanding of what is excluded being the end points of a mathematical set. Similarly, "inclusive" means "including the end points of the mathematical set".

Comment: @Rafeq Answering the question you posed to FumbleFingers, the ambiguity comes from the fact that sometimes when people say "from 13 to 17" they mean "from the first day of 13 to the first day of 17." Colloquial usage can vary between 13 to 17 inclusive, and 13 inclusive 17 exclusive. Because there's no way to ask for clarification in a written medium, they're getting ahead of the problem and eliminating any ambiguity by specifying that it's fully inclusive.

Comment: As the answer says, *"inclusive" doesn’t change the meaning here.* But it's there ***just to avoid any ambiguity***. Consider *He works **from 9 to 5***, which means he's probably on his way home a few minutes after 5 o'clock. Compare that to *This playground is reserved for children **from age 5 to 9*** - which in reality is almost certainly intended to allow a 9-year-old child right up to and including the day before his 10th birthday. That's to say, there *are* contexts where such ranges are interpreted differently (but the *intended* "clusivity" is usually obvious in any given case).